# Проблема class ... is public should be declared in a file named

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема при компиляции прлєкта.
Надо создать класс и его наследника и переопределенній метод. Возле каждого класса пишет class ... is public should be declared in a file named ... и предлагает переименовать файл. Как я понимаю проблема в том, что классы надо было расскидать в разные файлы? Но я читал, что можно и несколько в одном держать. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
package l2;

public class Man {
    int age;
    double weight;
    String name, gender;
    public Man (int age, double weight, String name, String gender) {
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public int ageChanged (int n_a){
        age = n_a;
        return age;
    }
    public double weightChanged (double n_w){
        weight = n_w;
        return weight = n_w;
    }
    public String nameChanged (String n_n){
        name = n_n;
        return name;
    }
}
public class Student extends Man {
    int y_of_s;
    public Student (int age, double weight, String name, String gender, int y_of_s){
        Super (age, weight, name, gender);
        this.y_of_s = y_of_s;
    }
    public int y_of_sChanged (int n_y_of_s){
        y_of_s += n_y_of_s;
        return y_of_s;
    }
    public int ageChanged (int n_a){
        age += n_a;
        return age;
    }
}
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student p1 = new Student (18, 67.3, "Anton", "male", 2016);
        Man p2 = new Man (45, 67.3, "Jack", "male");
        System.out.println("Возраст p1: "+p1.age+"; год обучения p1: "+p1.y_of_s+";");
        System.out.println("Возраст p2: "+p1.age+";");
        System.out.println("Возраст p1 (новый): "+p1.ageChanged (1)+"; год обучения p1 (новый): "+p1.y_of_sChanged (1)+";");
        System.out.println("Возраст p2 (новый): "+p1.ageChanged (46)+";");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете положить несколько классов в один файл, но публичным из них может быть только один. И его имя должно при этом совпадать с названием файла.

Идея в том, что вы кладёте в файл публичный класс, и мелкие приватные классы, относящиеся к нему (всяческие хелперы, например, или внутренняя функциональность).

Смысл такого дизайна — заставить программистов правильно организовывать код, используя файлы для разделения функциональности.

Comment: тогда спрошу Вас о следуещем: у меня єтот public Main или Man должен быть?

Comment: да, говорю об классе

Comment: @MuscledBoy: Я вижу у вас два класса — `Man` и `Main`. Положите каждый из них в отдельный файл.

Comment: @MuscledBoy: Решение о том, какой из классов объявлять `public`, а какой нет, должно приниматься вами вне зависимости от раскладки кода по файлам.

Comment: извините заглупый вопрос, но совсем запутался. У сеня есть класс человек и его наследник студент. Точка входа в программу метод main, а онведь принадлежит классу Main. Или значит он нужен (класс Main)?

Comment: @MuscledBoy: Метод `main` **не обязан** быть в классе `Main`. Но в принципе отдельный класс для логики программы — это правильно, так что положить `main` и логику программы в отдельный класс, как это сделано у вас, имеет смысл.

Comment: последний вопрос,теперь пишет constructor man in class man cannot be applied to given types в строчке с конструктором Student

Comment: все нашел ошибку,извините. за беспокойство